# Avoiding spacing and fixing a unique dimension in displayed images with marquee

Tags: css, html, marquee

I have a web application in which I'd like to create a image slide show with the tag `marquee`. I have this snippet

```
<table >
  <tr><img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/App_Themes/UA/images/img_pi_bkg_top.png" style="width : 797px">
  </tr>
</table>
<div  style="background : #3F2D2C; margin-left : 14px;" >
  <MARQUEE SCROLLDELAY="19" Truespeed BGCOLOR="#3F2D2C">
    <table cellspacing = 20>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=55856&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56196&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56551&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56460&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56545&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56557&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56407&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56392&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56479&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56321&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56451&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.universityarchives.com/DisplayImage.aspx?StockNumber=56454&ImageOrder=1&IsPremierePageItem=true" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </MARQUEE>
</div>
```

My problem is how do I avoid the space between the image and the `div` tag even when I put `style="margin-top : 0px` the space still exist. How can I fix a unique dimension of all the displayed images?

Comment: You know the `marquee` tag is non standard right?

Comment: [There is no `marquee` tag in the spec. So you are basically using an invalid tag](http://www.goer.org/htmlhorror/htmlhorror1.html)

Comment: You have created a tag called `marquee`, this is not standard. I think you may want to create a `div` with the `id` as 'marquee' i.e. `<div id= "marquee"></div>`

Comment: how can i change the code to do the same with another `tag`

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquee_tag.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters - you have to close the image tag with a `/>` 
try removing the first table - with the image in it and then make the image `display:block`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2HDT/)

is that what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks it's working but i 'd like to fix the size of all images like the bigger one displayed, how can i do it?

Comment: get bigger images? or set a height for each one